# Mathjobs.org cover letter: Address to "Hiring Committee Member" or to faculty member listed on job posting?

Tags: job-search, application-cover-letter

On mathjobs.org, each posting often has at the bottom of the listing "further info." Sometimes the name and contact information for a faculty member is listed. Instead of addressing my cover letter, "Dear Hiring Committee Member," would it be better if I wrote, "Dear (name of faculty member)?"

Comment: Perhaps you could use the generic "Dear sir or madam."

Comment: @aparente001 To me, that sounds old fashioned, is it also perceived this way by search committees?

Comment: It's not old fashioned, it's classic.  And non-sexist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  Although the person listed for further information might be on the search committee, they certainly won't be the only member of the committee.  Furthermore, the person listed for further information might not even be on the committee.

Comment: I was very confused by this, so thanks for clarifying.

Comment: For example, the "for further information" person listed on the advertisement that my institution just posted on mathjobs.org is a staff member in the human resources office and not a faculty member at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with "
To whom it may concern".